# Update Key in snapshotChanges before using it in same method

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

because of removing $key from angularfire2 in latest version i am trying to add the key before i return it in my getAll service method like:

```
getAll(): Observable<any> {
return this.loginService.loginData.take(1).flatMap( userdata => {
                var RefItems = this.loginService.afDB.list(`/games/${userdata.gameid}/categories/`);
                RefItems.snapshotChanges().map(categories => {
                    return categories.map(m => ({ key: m.key, ...m.payload.val() }));
                });
                return RefItems.valueChanges().map( categories => {
                    return categories.map((category) => {
                        category["matches"] = this.matchesService.getAll(category["key"]);
                        return category;
                    })
                });
            })
        }
```

but it seems to be to late(the key isnt in the valueChanges method), anybody have an idea for me? :)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know where exactly problem lies.
And not certain what part:

```
 return RefItems.valueChanges().map( categories => {
                return categories.map((category) => {
                    category["matches"] = 
 this.matchesService.getAll(category["key"]);
                    return category;
                })
            });
```

do, but you can try modify code to form of:

```
getAll(): Observable<any> {
    return this.loginService.loginData.take(1).flatMap( userdata => {    
        this.loginService.afDB.list(`/games/${userdata.gameid}/categories/`)
         .snapshotChanges().map(categories => {
                    return categories.map(m => ({ key: m.key}));
                }).subscribe(vals => {
                    return vals.map(val=> val.key);
            });
    });
}
```

It will call probable that subscription can not be assigned to Observable, but you will figure it out. Hope it help you a little